# ¿Por qué esta funcion no reconoce un String concatenado?

Tags: c++, arduino

Soy nuevo en Arduino, y estoy probando a consumir una API en Arduino. El problema es el siguiente. Como pueden ver, tengo una variable String llamada *url*, donde almaceno una parte de la direccion de la api y luego le concateno el valor de la variable usuario que obtengo del puerto serial(para probar ingreso 1).
En las siguiente linea tengo una variable llamada *urla* que tiene dentro la misma ruta pero sin concatenar (más o menos como quedaría la anterior despues de concatenar)

Entonces el problema surge aquí. En la funcion **begin()**, si envío la variable *urla* (la que **no** concatena), todo funciona correctamente, pero si envío *url* (la que concatena), no funciona. Por qué, si son aparentemente iguales?

```
if(Serial.available() > 0){

String usuario = String(Serial.readString());
Serial.println("Parametro recibido: " + usuario);

String url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + usuario;
String urla = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";

if(url.equals(urla)) {
  Serial.println("iguales");
}

if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {

  HTTPClient http;
  Serial.println(url);

  http.begin(url);

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  if (httpCode > 0) {
   Serial.println("dentro de if");
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(payload);

  } 
  http.end();
}
```

}

Comment: creo que al inicio en el loop no espera a que ingreses un valor, entonces continua y asigna un valor por defecto, una observación seria intentar entrar en un bucle infinito hasta que la variable `usuario`contenga valor y de allí saltar el bucle y poder hacer todas las peticiones.

Answer (score 1):

El detalle está en que `Serial.readString()` retorna lo ingresado por el usuario, **incluyendo** cualquier combinación de "\n" y "\r" que envíe el cliente. Eso hace a las dos URL distintas y a la variable `url`, una URL no válida.

La solución es simple. Aplica el método `trim()` para eliminar cualquier *white space* (espacio, \r, \ņ, \t, etc.) al principio y al final del usuario:

Agrega esta línea luego del `readString`:

```
String usuario = String(Serial.readString());    
usuario.trim();
```